# Change a precise item color in a listview in JAVAFX without changing all of them

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml

I have looked many topics on the forum but don't know how to do it.I really need your help

Basically I have 4 listviews.

3 of which are static which are preloaded  at initialization in the controller(always the same values in it).They contain String.
My goal is to click on any items (preloaded at initialization) contained on the 3 different listviews and have it appeared on the fourth list view with a certain color(for example here I chose blue and red) depending on a criteria which is not important here.

The fact is that my code does work and does change the color on the fourth listview **BUT IT CHANGES THE COLOR ALSO OF ALL THE PREVIOUS ITEMS ALREADY LOADED** on the fourth listview which I don't want to happen(I just want to set a color for a precise item not for every one).
THE first 2 static listviews named listevolview and listesolview: when you click on any item of this 2 listviews, the same item is supposed to appear on the fourth list view named listeclairanceview in red .
the third static list view named listeexoview: when you click this list view the item selected is suppposed to appear in the fourth one in blue.

To sum up the news item appear in the listefrequenceview (the fourth listview) with the good color but the color of the previous items are not anymore with good color(they are all with the same color: the color of the last item loaded on the fourth list view);

***I have my example here at the end of the code.So Here When I click on the first list view it's ok becaue it becomes red
then the next item is blue BUT the first item is not red anymore.
It's the same problem with the third picture where everything becomes red***.
By the way I did not put all the obvious methods for a question of understanding.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

import com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.Task;

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
//import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Cell;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import java.net.Socket;
//import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
public class SampleController implements Initializable{

     
        /**
     * 
     */
    
    
        


        
        
        
        
        
         @FXML
         private ListView<String> listefrequenceview;
         
         @FXML
         private ListView<String> listevolview;
         
         @FXML
         private ListView<String> listesolview;
         
         @FXML
         private ListView<String> listeexoview;
         
        private  InterfaceClairances interfaceclairance= new InterfaceClairances();
        
    
        private ToggleGroup toggglegroup= new ToggleGroup();
        
        
          @FXML
            private ToggleButton avion1;

            @FXML
            private ToggleButton avion2;

            @FXML
            private ToggleButton avion3;
         
         
         
            @FXML
          public  void clairancesol(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        
                
                        interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence().add(listesolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                        interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().add(new Clairance(listesolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(),3));
                        //interfaceclairance.getListeclairancespilotesSOL().get(listesolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).setEtat(2);  // etat 2 : traitement en cours
                        //this.listefrequenceview.setItems(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence());
                        this.listefrequenceview.getItems().add(listesolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                
            }
            
            @FXML
              public  void clairancevol(MouseEvent arg0) {
                            
                    
                            interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence().add(listevolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                            interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().add(new Clairance(listevolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(),3));
                            //interfaceclairance.getListeclairancespilotesSOL().get(listevolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).setEtat(2);  // etat 2 : traitement en cours
                            //this.listefrequenceview.setItems(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence());
                            this.listefrequenceview.getItems().add(listevolview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    
                }
            
            @FXML
              public  void clairanceexo(MouseEvent arg0) {
                            
                    
                            interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence().add(listeexoview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                            interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().add(new Clairance(listeexoview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(),4));
                            //interfaceclairance.getListeclairancespilotesSOL().get(listeexoview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).setEtat(2);  // etat 2 : traitement en cours(demande du pilote) etat 3: traité par le controleur(ou demande du controleur) etat 4: traité et collationné par le pilote etat 1: non traité. 
                            //listefrequenceview.setItems(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancesfrequence());
                            this.listefrequenceview.getItems().add(listeexoview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    
                }
         
        
        
            
            
            
        
        
    
    
        
    
              
               
               
            
        

        
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
               
            
              
              this.listesolview.getItems().addAll(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancespilotesSOL());
               
               this.listevolview.getItems().addAll(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancespilotesVOL());
               
               this.listeexoview.getItems().addAll(interfaceclairance.getObslisteclairancespilotesEXO());
               
               this.toggglegroup.getToggles().addAll(avion1,avion2,avion3);
               
               this.listefrequenceview.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {

                    @Override
                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
                        return new ListCell<String>() {

                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(String value, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(value, empty);
                                
                                setText(empty ? "" : value);
                                
                                if (SampleController.this.interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().get(SampleController.this.interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().size()-1).getEtat()==3) {
                                   
                                   
                               
                                    
                                    setStyle( "-fx-text-fill: red;");
                             
                                }
                                else {
                                    
                                     setStyle("-fx-text-fill: skyblue;");
                                }
                               
                                    
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
             
              
        }

}

public class InterfaceClairances {
     
    private ArrayList<Clairance> listeclairancespilotesSOL;
    
    private ArrayList<Clairance> listeclairancesfrequence;
    
    private ArrayList<Clairance> listeclairancespilotesVOL;
    
    private ArrayList<Clairance> listeclairancespilotesEXO;
    
    private ObservableList<String> obslisteclairancespilotesSOL=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    private ObservableList<String> obslisteclairancespilotesVOL=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    private ObservableList<String> obslisteclairancespilotesEXO=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    private ObservableList<String> obslisteclairancesfrequence = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
public class Clairance {
    
    private String clairance;
    private int etat;


first:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEpK9.png
second: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoQU1.png
third:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm8w5.png
```

Comment: Please update your question with a well-formatted [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And definitely read that link because just the process of building the MCVE may lead to  your solution.

Comment: as already suggested: [mcve] - mind the __M__! and put a bit effort into code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Something has to be wrong with your implementation of the ListCell, but I can not tell what exactly, because I do not understand the if-condition in your code. Nevertheless, here is a simple and working example which helps you to find your mistake hopefully:

**view.fxml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="org.example.Controller">
    <ListView fx:id="sourceListView1">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <String fx:value="1.1"/>
                <String fx:value="1.2"/>
                <String fx:value="1.3"/>
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ListView>
    <ListView fx:id="sourceListView2">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <String fx:value="2.1"/>
                <String fx:value="2.2"/>
                <String fx:value="2.3"/>
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ListView>
    <ListView fx:id="sourceListView3">
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                <String fx:value="3.1"/>
                <String fx:value="3.2"/>
                <String fx:value="3.3"/>
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
    </ListView>
    <ListView fx:id="targetListView"/>
</HBox>
```

**Controller.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String>
            sourceListView1, // your "listevolview" or volListView... (use lowerCamelCase-Notation)
            sourceListView2,
            sourceListView3;
    @FXML
    private ListView<Item>
            targetListView; // your "listeclairanceview" or clearanceListView

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        // Create a custom list cell for the target list view:
        targetListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Item> call(ListView<Item> param) {
                return new ListCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) {
                            setText("");
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;");
                        } else {
                            setText(item.getText());

                            // Logic for setting the right color here:
                            if (item.getSource() == sourceListView1 || item.getSource() == sourceListView2)
                                setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue;");
                            else
                                setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        // Add item to the target list view when selection of a source list view changes:
        List<ListView<String>> sourceListViews = new ArrayList<>();
        sourceListViews.add(sourceListView1);
        sourceListViews.add(sourceListView2);
        sourceListViews.add(sourceListView3);
        sourceListViews.forEach(listView
                -> listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)
                -> targetListView.getItems().add(new Item(listView, newValue))));
    }
}
```

**Item.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

/**
 * Item class for the target list view to have the information needed to be able to differentiate the source
 * and to be able to set the color accordingly.
 */
public class Item {

    private final ListView<String> // Here your distinction; Should better not be the control itself
            source;                // but maybe an enum type you can create.

    private final String text; // The String to be shown in the target list view.

    // Constructor:
    public Item(ListView<String> source, String text) {
        this.source = source;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // Getters:
    public ListView<String> getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**App.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

Comment: thanks for your help !! I will try this model tomorrrow.

Comment: Actually you were right there is a problem with the if condition.I tried with an obvious if condition and it worked well.But I don't know why it doesn't work though.The if condition is trying to know the state of the int parameter(Etat) of a clairance which is the last added clairance in the listeclairancesfrequence.That's why I use size-1 to get the last clairance in the list.SampleController.this.interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().get(SampleController.this.interfaceclairance.getListeclairancesfrequence().size()-1).getEtat()*** the line in the get() is the index of the list